# Angular merge nested arrays

Tags: angularjs

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    'title' : 'cats',
    'names' : [
      'felix',
      'tom',
      ... more names
    ]
  },
  {
    'title' : 'dogs',
    'names' : [
      'fido',
      'rover',
      ... more names
    ]
  },
  {
    ... More animal types
]
```

And I would like to have the following:

```
<p ng-repeat='name in names'>{{ name }}</p>
```

But, to do that I really need to at some stage set

```
$scope.names = ['felix', 'tom', 'fido', rover'];
```

My question is: is there an 'Angular' way to merge arrays or take content from multiple places from one object? Or do I need to use a for loop with a concat function to create the array I use?

Comment: you would need to do your data mapping

Comment: Could you try an outer 'loop' of `animal in animals` and an inner one of `name in animal.names`? I'm not sure if that would work, or is idiomatic, so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just defined `names` based on your data, [demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/QbNejP).

```
$scope.names = function() {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], animals.map(function(animal) {
    return animal.names;
  }));
};
```

Then use that method in your view

```
<p ng-repeat='name in names()'>{{ name }}</p>
```

Or we could assume the list of animals won't change, and use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) for readability, [demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/VLaoer?editors=101).

```
$scope.names = _.chain(animals)
  .pluck('names')
  .flatten()
  .value()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not likely to be a core functions for such feature in javascript nor in angular as angular is just mvc framework on javascript. function you need is not common enough for javascript, or specific enough for mvc